# Shopify AJAX Request - e.preventDefault Not Working

Tags: javascript, ajax, shopify

I have a cart popup that shows the contents of the cart using an AJAX request.  Inside this popup, I have an "X" link meant to remove that line item from the cart.  However, when I use the following code,

```
$('#remove-from-cart').click(function(e) {  
      var link = $(this).attr('href');
      // Preven link normal behavior
      e.preventDefault();   
      $.ajax({
        url: link,
        type:'GET',
        success: function(data){
          $('#receipt-wrapper .receipt-row-2').html($(data).find('.line-item-container').html());
        }
      });
  });
```

the normal link behavior of the X link still happens, meaning it takes you to the updated cart page immediately.

HTML of "remove link"

```
<div class="grid__item receipt--hide small--one-sixth medium--one-sixth large--one-twelfth xlarge--one-twelfth icon-remove">
    <p class="cart__product-meta">
         <a href="/cart/change?line={{ forloop.index }}&amp;quantity=0" id="remove-from-cart">
            {% include 'svg-icon-remove' %}
         </a>
    </p>
</div>
```

What am I doing wrong? (I'm using an identical block of JS code to make the popup appear and it works for that)

Thanks!

Comment: is your ajax call is getting called, put it in `document.ready`

Comment: `{{ forloop.index }}` is this angular code

Answer (score 0):

Remove `href` from anchor tag and use in in the click function.,

`Take a data attribute and add the required url in the data attribute.`

```
<div class="grid__item receipt--hide small--one-sixth medium--one-sixth large--one-twelfth xlarge--one-twelfth icon-remove">
    <p class="cart__product-meta">
         <a id="remove-from-cart" data-url="/cart/change?line={{ forloop.index }}&amp;quantity=0">
            {% include 'svg-icon-remove' %}
         </a>
    </p>
</div>
```

Now, refer the data attribute using this in the function.

```
$('#remove-from-cart').click(function(e) {  
      var link = this.data("url")
      // Preven link normal behavior
      e.preventDefault();   
      $.ajax({
        url: link,
        type:'GET',
        success: function(data){
          $('#receipt-wrapper .receipt-row-2').html($(data).find('.line-item-container').html());
        }
      });
  });
```

Comment: I just gave it a shot, but it doesn't have any effect unfortunately.

Comment: is it still redirecting you? , `console.log(this.data("url"))`, check what is coming in it

Comment: I placed the console command before e.preventDefault but nothing shows

Comment: take $(this) instead of this. `$(this).data("href")`

Comment: I gave that a shot, but still it doesn't do anything and nothing gets logged in the console

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126391/discussion-between-sravan-and-kevmon).